# Get value from object by value from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and I need to get some data by array values.

```
let array = ["Clothing", "Home", "Payments"];
const expenses = {
  clothing: '#FF9494',
  food: '#0099CC',
  healthCare: '#C58BE2',
  home: '#FF8A00',
  recreation: '#669900',
  payments: '#CC0D01',
};
```

I need to get an array of object values

```
['#FF9494', '#FF8A00', '#CC0D01']

array.map(el => {
  let target = expenses.map(obj => obj === el);
  return target;
})
```

Comment: (1) You'd need to convert your array of the properties you want to actual property names (in this case, lower-casing is sufficient), then (2) map over those keys and get the values using bracket notation. What's the specific issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expenses is an object, that means that you can *look up properties by key*:

```
 array.map(key => expenses[key.toLowerCase()])
```